# How to prove it? I found that is zero for values $x< x_0,$ but for $x \in \mathbb{R}?$

Tags: calculus

Define a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 \leq f'(x) \leq f(x)$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that if there is an $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = 0 \implies \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Please use LaTeX

Comment: Here's a hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall's_inequality#Differential_form

Comment: In the future you should include a link the the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) by including the following text: `[MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f'(x)\geq0$, $f$ is monotonically increasing.  We know $f(x)\geq0$ so $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq x_0$.  Let $x_0<x<x_0+1$.  By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$f(x)=\int_{x_0}^xf'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\leq\int_{x_0}^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\leq(x-x_0)f(x)$$  since $f$ is increasing.  Since $0<x-x_0<1$, this is a contradiction unless $f(x)=0.$  By continuity, $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq x_0+1$.  By induction, $f(x)=0$ for all real $x$.

Comment: Thanks! Could there be a method without using integrals?

Comment: @Jack By the mean value theorem, $f(x)=(x-x_0)f'(c)$ for some $x_0<c<x$, and $f'(c)\leq f(c)\leq f(x)$

Comment: Thanks! Have a great day

Answer (score 3):

Saulspatz's proof is good, but another standard proof (which is common in ODE theory) uses the following argument:
$$f'(x)\leq f(x)\Rightarrow f'(x)-f(x)\leq 0 \Rightarrow e^{-x}f'-e^{-x}f\leq 0\Rightarrow (e^{-x}f)'\leq 0$$
Integrating both sides we get:
$$0\geq \int_{x_0}^x (e^{-t}f)'dt=e^{-x}f(x)-e^{x_0}f(x_0)=e^{-x}f(x)$$

But since $e^{-x}\geq 0$ we conclude that $f\leq 0$. Since $f\geq 0$ we conclude that $f=0$.

Notice that we assumed that $x>x_0$ - think what happens in the other direction (what changes in the proof?)